# How can I parallelize an image reading function in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My main aim is to read in around 16k images for a Data science project and I am barely able to perform that serially.

I have performed some parallelization in c++, but I am unfamiliar with using it in python. Essentially, all I need is to parallelize a for loop that calls a function that reads in the image using the matplotlib.image package and returns the image object. I then simply append that object to list. Here is the function,

```
def read_img(name):
    
    try:
        img = mpimg.imread(name)
        return img
    except: 
        return("Did not find image")
```

I ran my code for 100, 1000 and then 5000 images in one go to see if it can run at all, and it ran fine until I ran it for 5000 and my jupyter notebook just crashed. My system has 24gb ram and 12 cores so I def need to find a way to parallelize this.

I know there are 2 modules in python for parallelization, **multiprocessing and joblib** but I am not sure how to approach this problem which I know is very basic but any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python `ThreadPoolExecutor` [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Here is the general program which is not perfect but if you fill this should work

```
# import or some variable from your code mpimg

def read_img(name):
    try:
        img = mpimg.imread(name)
        return img
    except: 
        return("Did not find image")

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

# suppose the files contains th 16k file names
files = ['f1.jpg', 'f2.jpg']
future_to_file = {}
images_read = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for file in files:
        future = executor.submit(read_img, file)
        future_to_file[future] = file
    
    for future in as_completed(future_to_file):
        file = future_to_file[future]
        img_read = future.result()
        if img_read != 'Did not find image':
            images_read.append((file, img_read))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I consulted my professor and actually realized that my whole approach was unnecessary. I had to use one of the data loader functions of Pytorch or tensorflow, that process images in batches instead of loading all of them in one go. I will def try your approach for other regression modelling that I performed previously. They worked fine but just took too long.